# What are my options for streaming chatlogs live to Amazon S3 from Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are using a cluster of node.js servers to power our chat system.

We would like users to be able to see their previous conversations with any other given user and as such need to store chat logs.

Since these never need to be edited or queried in any way it does not make sense to store them in a database and as such we would like to simply keep them as simple json files stored on Amazon S3.

Using Amazons PHP api it is now possible to use standard fopen/fwrite commands making streaming to S3 possible.  But in this case we need to do it with Node.js.

Essentially we would like to be able to open a stream when the users begin chatting, and append to the end of a chatlog file on S3, live while the users are chatting.

If this is not possible, what are our other options?

We have considered creating local writeStreams on the node.js servers, using them to essentially buffer the data, detect the end of a conversation and then upload/replace the file to S3.  It just seems overly verbose and given the the node.js servers are within Amazons network it feels like a poor mans solution when clearly streaming to S3 is now a possibility in PHP.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Since these never need to be edited or queried in any way it does not make sense to store them in a database...
```

I don't agree with your logic here: Just because you only want to write once and read-many,  doesn't mean a DB is not an appropriate solution. You could probably use S3, but given the brief description of your problem I would think a classic DB solution is going to serve you better in the long run. If you go the DB route, you have lots of well supported options within AWS (RDS-SQL Server, Postgres, MYSQL), DynamocDB and SimpleDB.

Even if you end up storing the chats on S3, its not unreasonable to think you may end up storing the metadata about each chat in a DB such as DynamoDB. How many chats are you going to store? If you end up with 100's of thousands or millions of seperate chat files, how will you navigate a user to the right one when they want it? This is a where a DB will come in handy, and then it begs the question, if you are going to use a DB to store the metadata, why not just store the content as well?

Comment: Indeed it's looking like the way we are going to go. It just feels expensive and unnecessary somehow. Chat thread ID's are unique, generated from an md5 hash of the particpants userids (the userid's are ordered and its a little more complex than this)  This way when a user begins talking to someone they have an existing history with we can perform the threadID algorithm and get the correct ID everytime, which could be a file. I'm actually leaning towards using DynamoDB for everything and keeping a cached copy of the most recent 20 items in a memcached elasticache instance to keep costs down.

Comment: I suppose going the DB route would also allow us to potentially add multi-user chat if needed sometime in the future.  I guess we could use our thread_id algorithm to generate the hash key in dynamodb, using a timestamp as the range key and also using the thread_id as the key for the cached items.  Does this sound like a reasonable solution to you?  While using an RDB is attractive cost wise, we have fallen in love with the no hassle scaling that dynamodb offers us.

Comment: Seems reasonable. My going in position is always that you will ALWAYS find uses for data once you have it accumulated, and its better to have it in a way that makes it easy to use/implement that new stuff when the opportunity arises.